# Deduct tax from shipping in review order?

Tags: tax, shipping-methods

I have applied GSt tax for Australia, every thing works fine but during checkout in review order it shows shipping amount by deducting the gst tax from it.
and add that deducted tax of shipping in total tax of product.

Please see the attachment.
I want the selected shipping method value should be show without any tax deduction in review order

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove tax then go to Admin Panel -> configure -> sales -> Tax and remove setting of including tax.

Comment: i donot want to remove tax, but the tax should not be calculated for shipping cost, if i select 8.50, then in review order it should come 8.50.  but for now it deducts the 10% from shipping then show in order review.